# Redux add websocket as prop

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux, react-redux

I have react application with that needed single `websocket` connection, so i connect `websocket` from redux action and trying to set `websocket` instance as prop; so I can access this instance any ware in my application

```
const initWebSocket = uri => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(uri)
    return {
        type: WEB_SOCKET_CONNECTION_SUCCESS,
        ws
    }
}
// reducer
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case WEB_SOCKET_CONNECTION_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, ws: action.ws}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

but aster state change `ws` is empty object

Comment: might I suggest not keeping websocket instance in store, instead add SEND_MESSAGE, ON_RECIEVE_MSG and CLOSE_WEBSOKET as redux actions?

Answer (score 2):

It's technically possibly to put a Websocket connection instance into a Redux store, but that's a bad idea.  The Redux docs [discourage putting anything that's not serializable in the Redux store](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable).

The right place for Websockets and other persistent connection objects in a Redux app is inside of middleware.  In fact, there's already [dozens of existing middleware for managing Websocket connections](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware-sockets-adapters.md) available.